# Why Does My Apex Map Appear To Get Overwritten?

Tags: salesforce, testng, apex

I am trying to build a test data factory to create a number of contacts and attach them to an account. The method should return a map of account Id to List of contacts. However, my test class is failing and I can see from the debug logs that all of the contacts are related to one account. I have put debug statements in place so that I can see the map being built inside a loop and it looks okay. Then when I look at the map immediately outside the loop it contains 4 copies of the same contact. Here is my code followed by the debug statements. I've kept it simple by using 2 accounts each with one contact. I'd really like to understand what's going wrong here if anyone can help please.

```
public static Map<Id, List<Contact>> createContacts(List<Account> accounts, Integer numOfContacts) {

Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapOfAccountIdToListOfContacts = New Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
List<Contact> addedContacts = New List<Contact>();
List<Contact> accContacts = New List<Contact>();

    for(Account ac :accounts) {
        accContacts.clear();
        for(Integer i=0;i<numOfContacts;i++) {
            Contact newContact = New Contact(LastName='TestContact' + i,
                                          Email = 'TestContact' + i + '@testco.com',
                                            AccountId = ac.Id);
            accContacts.add(newContact);
        }
        mapOfAccountIdToListOfContacts.put(ac.Id, accContacts);
        System.debug('Map.put=' + ac.id + ', ' + accContacts);
        addedContacts.addAll(accContacts);
    }
    insert addedContacts;
    for(Id key :mapOfAccountIdToListOfContacts.keyset()) {
        System.debug('Contacts=' + mapOfAccountIdToListOfContacts.get(key));
    }
    return mapOfAccountIdToListOfContacts;
}
```

and the log output:

[It said the log was spam so here's an image of the log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/197ug.png)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are destroying old entries in the map because you are calling `accContacts.clear();`. I don't think the references to the contacts are completely gone, the test probably inserts them fine via `insert addedContacts;` - but they're not in the map anymore.

Change the call to make a fresh list in every loop. You can reuse the variable name, just allocate new memory. `accContacts = New List<Contact>();` in the beginning of the loop instead of `clear` should do the trick.